# Scrabble Probability

Tags: probability

Scrabble player 1 and Scrabble player 2 each draw $7$ letters from a bag of $100$ at the start of a Scrabble game.  If there are $6$ "T"s in a bag of Scrabble letters, what is the probability player 1 will draw $3$ of them?

Answer (score 1):

Since Scrabble tiles are taken without replacement, you would use the [hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) to find the probability of 3 successes in 7 draws, given that there are 6 potential successes in the entire population of 100 tiles.

The hypergeometric distribution is defined as $\dfrac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$, where $N$ is the total population (here, the 100 tiles), $n$ is the number of draws you will make (in this case, 7 draws), $K$ is the total number of successes in the population (the 6 T tiles), and $k$ is the number of successful draws you will make (in this case, 3).

Plugging in the numbers will get you the result:

$P(X = 3) = \dfrac{\binom{6}{3}\binom{94}{4}}{\binom{100}{7}} \approx 0.00381. $

You can think about this intuitively as follows: we're choosing 3 "successes" out of 6 possible successes, and 4 "failures" out of 94 possible failures, and there are 100 choose 7 possible ways of choosing any combination of tiles at all.

Comment: Great, although I thought it might complicate things if another player is drawing 7. But I guess that would depend on when they drew the 7, if they alternated or not ... so the question is incomplete.

Comment: Hi, it looks like you commented on one of my comments that I had recently deleted. I'll post a more in-depth comment sometime tomorrow (it's 4:37 AM here...oops) going through a number of drawing cases if you want. Basically, my point is if at any point you have knowledge of what tiles remain, then the probabilities for further draws will change. Let me know if you want a more in-depth explanation than that.

Comment: Hey, edited my response because I forgot Scrabble tiles weren't replaced when drawn. My bad >_>

Comment: @JohnQ actually, since we can't see the other players' tiles, it doesn't matter what they are: the space of possibilities for what the other players could have leaves all the tiles with the same probability of being pulled from the bag by player 1 as they would have had if player 1 was the only person drawing. (this is one of those things that sneaks up on a lot of people, actually: if all we care about is what's in our own hand, then it doesn't matter how many other people are drawing, or how the drawing is done among them!)